# How to Fix File History On Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, file-history

A recent crash on my Windows 10 computer made me have to restore the system with a System Image.

The System Image was made in December 2016.

It worked just fine but the problem is that when I went to my File History to restore my more recent files it showed that I only had the files from December 2016. I used the same external hard drive to save both my File History and my System Image so I'm sure that's what's causing the problem.

File History of course has started saving what I just restored but still won't show anything that it saved after December 2016. I have a lot of important files that I was keeping backed up and I'm certain they are still on there. I just can't access them like normal.

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: I've looked through the external hard drive folders for the File History and found the folders but for some reason the recent stuff has disappeared. For some reason though some folders have files as recent as 7/31/17 but the Desktop folder and similar ones only have the December 2016 files. 

For some reason the recent backup files are gone after the system restore from the System Image. I really see no reason for this to have happened. I looked at the external hard drive on a separate computer and it's showing the same thing.

Comment: Update: I don't know why but for some reason I'm now finding the missing files in the folders but the option to restore them in the Control Panel is still not there. They just sort of showed up after a while. It would be nice to do it from the Control Panel but I suppose I'll have to do it manually.

I still would like to know if anyone has encountered this problem before.

Comment: And now the files are gone again. This is weird.

Comment: Whatever you do, IF you see the actual files on your external drive, copy the WHOLE folder to another location--PREFERABLY a SEPARATE external drive.  Unfortunately, FH, MAY have seen the dates, and decided to "clean up", deleting more recent file copies.  It is POSSIBLE that, if you don't modify anything else on that drive, you can recover some of the DELETED files from the cleanup.  (Deleted files don't really delete the data in most all of the sectors, only marks the sectors as "available".  Your external drive might be the only chance of recovery.